# html 5 forms input type time with min and max

Tags: html, forms

I have been able to use input type date with min and max attributes in a form I am designing taking advantage as much as possible of HTML 5. Nevertheless I am not able to do the same if input type is **time**.

Relevant code:

```
<input style='width:120px' required name='dia' id='dia' type='date' min="1991-01-01" max="2014-05-12">
<input style='width:80px' required name='hora' id='hora' type="time" min="08:00:00" max="20:00:00"/>
```

(min and max in the latter are ignored)

Other relevant information:

- As far as I can tell the HTML 5 specification allows min and max in both cases.
- I am using minimizr and webshims for this form which makes input date fields available in FF, etc.
- No different behavior detected between recent major browsers.
- A site like W3C schools mentions min and max for date but not for time which may indicate a general lack of enthusiasm for min and max as attributes for time.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

It works. It get triggered on oubmit saying type a time bigger or equal to 08:00. (Tested in chrome)
Some other browser ignore attribute min, max, required so pay attention to do it with JS too.

Comment: Thanks. After clearing an apparently unrelated javascript error pressing arrows in the time input starts time at the minimum value in FF (this is through webshims). In Opera pressing the arrow starts at 00:00 which is the type of thing that was leading me to wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with max and min in time input and I discovered that if you have a form with ordinary submit input button on Chrome it will get triggered.
But on the other hand, if you make your javascript submit the form with or without a confirmation from the user, it does not work. It will submit the time never displaying the max and min value trigger message.
I have made an example to show what I mean.

```js
var confirmString = "Do you confirm?";
 
function sendRemote(){
  if (confirm(confirmString)==true) {
      document.getElementById('remoteForm').submit(); 
  } 
  else {
  } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>



<form action='/' method='post' id='remoteForm'>
  <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" min="00:00" max="09:59" required>
  <small>Max 9h59</small>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' value='Send with Ordinary Form Submit Input'> 
  <p>It tells you inserted a value that exceeds the maximum time</p>
  <br>
  <br>                            
  <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='sendRemote()'>Send with DOM submit</button>
  <p>It does not tell you inserted a value that exceeds the maximum time</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When using form.submit() validation is not triggered, you can write a script that will check the fields and display corresponding error messages.
On the other hand if you want to run the native validation just trigger a click on the submit button.

Comment: Thank you, yes I would like to run native validation. onclick="function()", if you have resources to suggest what I have to put inside function to activate the native validation, please share.

Comment: If what you want is display a confirmation window before sending the form:
`<form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="text" required />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                event.target.submit();
            }
        })
    </script>`

Comment: Thank you. In my case I need to display both a confirmation message and a message telling the user that the max or min of input were exceeded.

Comment: For the message you cannot use the native error messages?
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" required />
This will give you an error message next to the field